# Invalid Argument error when setting a push endpoint in GCP Pub/Sub

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-cloud-pubsub

I have verified access to my domain (http://ec2-54-67-124-251.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/) and registered it in APIs and Services.

[image: Domain access verification]

[image: APIs and Services]

But I still get "pubsub error INVALID_ARGUMENT" when setting it in the push endpoint.

[image: Error]

Any ideas?

Comment: The endpoint you are trying to use is not consistent with what the docs indicate that you need: [*"an HTTPS server with non-self-signed certificate accessible on the public web."*](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot can you please move your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint you are trying to use is not consistent with what the docs indicate that you need: *["an HTTPS server with non-self-signed certificate accessible on the public web."](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber)*